# I want to add "," in list at correct place using python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a long list but I am putting some values here so that someone can get an idea of data. I have a list and data is like:

```
amount=['1-100000','2000-60000','10-20000000','50000-800000']
```

output need to be like:

```
['1-100,000','2,000-60,000','10-20,000,000','50,000-800,000']
```

so basically I have a data set where the prices were shown like [1-100000] so I took that part of data set and converted it into a list so that it can be used separately, I need the output to be like the one I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
amount=['1-100000','2000-60000','10-20000000','50000-800000']
output = [f'{int(x.split("-")[0]):,}-{int(x.split("-")[1]):,}' for x in amount]
print(output)
```

output:

```
['1-100,000', '2,000-60,000', '10-20,000,000', '50,000-800,000']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a little more readable than the previous one (array is used to prevent constant copying of strings).

```
def add_commas(s):
    s1, s2 = s.split('-')

    def process(s_part):
        n, tmp_s = len(s_part), []

        for i in range(n):
            if i and not i % 3:
                tmp_s.append(',')
            tmp_s.append(s_part[n - i - 1])

        return ''.join(tmp_s[::-1])

    return process(s1) + '-' + process(s2)

def main():
    amount=['1-100000','2000-60000','10-20000000','50000-800000']

    return [add_commas(v) for v in amount]

print(main())
```

Output:

```
['1-100,000', '2,000-60,000', '10-20,000,000', '50,000-800,000']
```